# Should a rails migration be committed separately from schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

After generating / writing / running a Rails database migration, should the migration file and `db/schema.rb` be committed to version control separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some rake tasks that should be similar may behave differently if `schema.rb` is not in sync with migrations, for example:

After creating the database, if you run:

`rake db:migrate` - it'll run the migrations

`rake db:schema:load` - it'll use the `schema.rb`

Reseting the database:

`rake db:migrate:reset` - recreates the database running the migrations one by one.

`rake db:reset` - recreates the database using current version of `schema.rb`

In both cases, no matter which task you choose, the result should be the same. Normally, using `schema.rb` is preferred since it creates the database in one step, instead of passing for every single migration, but if it's not the same version as the migrations the results will be different.

Answer (score 3):

Most people I've seen commit them in a single commit.

It makes more sense to me that way. It makes sure that running a `rake db:migrate` on any revision doesn't modify `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Are there any implications in this as far as merge conflicts go?